# JavaScript не работает _${width}px_ Почему?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста: почему-то не срабатывает вот это - ${width}.
Net Beans (8.1) отказывается подтягивать переменную, видит эту запись просто как текст.
Что не так???

Вот код:

```
function quadro(width,height,color){
    var str = '<div style="width: ${width}px; height:${height}px; background:${color};"></div>';
    document.write(str);
}

quadro(200,100,"red");
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать `` кавычки вокруг всей строки.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <script>
        function quadro(width, height, color) {
            var str = `<div style="width: ${width}px; height:${height}px; background:${color};"></div>`;
            document.write(str);
        }

        quadro(200, 100, "red");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: странно, скопировал строку, вставил - все равно не хочет.(

Comment: Только что проверил и все работает. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: ??? почему-то не работает... Но все равно спасибо

Comment: даже тот код что полностью хтмл? Вы не в интернет эксплорере тестите? Возможно у вас уж очень старый браузер и он не поддерживает ES6.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals
Тут указана поддержка Template Literals, старайтесь не использовать данный синтаксис, если Вам ценны клиенты со всех браузеров)

Comment: Нет-Бинс, гад, не хочет видеть! )
Всем большое спасибо за  неравнодушие

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего делать так

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
           function quadro(width,height,color){
              var str = '<div style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px; background: ' + color + ';"></div>';
              document.write(str);
           }
           quadro(200,150,"green");
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```